# WPF MediaElement NaturalDuration Automatic Duration is 5 second, how i can change it?

Tags: c#, wpf, duration, mediaelement

WPF MediaElement when NaturalDuration is Automatic, Duration is 5 second, how i can change it?

```
.
.
var uri = new Uri(items[itemIndex++], UriKind.Absolute);
mediaElementMain.Clock = new MediaTimeline(uri).CreateClock();
.
.

private void mediaElementMain_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(mediaElementMain.NaturalDuration == Duration.Automatic)
    {
        //????
    }
}
```